# PLS 00302 component must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

Something happens that I dont understand.

here is a type declared:

```
type my_type is record (
    amount number(18,2),
    my_date date
)

my_variable my_type
```

...

```
for my_variable in (select sum(table_amount), table_date from table group by table_date)
loop
   dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.my_date);
   dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.amount)
end loop;
```

my_variable.my_date works good but my_variable.amount triggers a PLS00302 error that I dont understand.

```
table structure:
table_date date,
table_amount number(10,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop declares a local variable `my_variable` that shadows the previous declaration. You need to reference the column names and not the record's attributes:

```
DECLARE
  type my_type is record (
    amount number(18,2),
    my_date date
  );

  my_variable my_type;
BEGIN
  for my_variable in (select table_amount, table_date from table_name)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.table_date);
    dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.table_amount);
  end loop;
END;
/
```

Which is the same as:

```sql
DECLARE
  type my_type is record (
    amount number(18,2),
    my_date date
  );

  my_variable my_type;
BEGIN
  for not_my_variable in (select table_amount, table_date from table_name)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(not_my_variable.table_date);
    dbms_output.put_line(not_my_variable.table_amount);
  end loop;
END;
/
```

*(But is slightly clearer as you do not have the cursor loop variable shadowing the declared variable.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f9b3bb0ea892fcbf3f2fac18f2dcf0e6)*

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about explicit record types and implicit cursor for-loop record types. The `my_type` and `my_variable` you are declaring are never used. The `my_variable` in the cursor loop is a completely independent construct, that you just happen to have given the same name to. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) that is the:

> Name for the loop index that the cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares as a %ROWTYPE record variable of the type that cursor or *select_statement* returns.
>
> *record* is local to the cursor FOR LOOP statement. Statements inside the loop can reference *record* and its fields. They can reference virtual columns only by aliases. Statements outside the loop cannot reference *record*. After the cursor FOR LOOP statement runs, *record* is undefined.

So in a construct like:

```
for my_variable in (select sum(table_amount), table_date from table group by table_date)
```

the `my_variable` has the row type of the cursor query projection, and fields corresponding to the column expressions or their aliases.

You need to alias the `sum()`, and then refer to that alias, something like:

```
  for my_variable in (
    select sum(table_amount) as amount, table_date
    from my_table
    group by table_date
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.table_date);
    dbms_output.put_line(my_variable.amount);
  end loop;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=55935b544cb1b0284d6530055c648ded) with some names changed to be more consistent with what you are describing. Note that the record type and variable declaration are not needed.